# Add string to make row non-duplicated

Tags: awk

The last column of my tab-separated dataframe contains duplicated string for the ENSG-codes (ENSG00000169189 and ENSG00000076344), the ENST does not matter. For each duplicated ENSG-code i would like to paste a number on the ENSG strings that makes them non-duplicated. Please see output example.

in

```
16  ensembl_havana  intron  27257582    27268705    .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000169189;Parent=transcript:ENST00000361439
16  ensembl_havana  intron  27257582    27268705    .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000169189;Parent=transcript:ENST00000563273
16  ensembl_havana  intron  27268375    27268705    .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000169189;Parent=transcript:ENST00000567710
16  ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000076344;Parent=transcript:ENST00000316163
16  ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000076344;Parent=transcript:ENST00000359740
16  ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000076344;Parent=transcript:ENST00000397770
```

out

```
16  ensembl_havana  intron  27257582    27268705    .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000169189_1;Parent=transcript:ENST00000361439
16  ensembl_havana  intron  27257582    27268705    .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000169189_2;Parent=transcript:ENST00000563273
16  ensembl_havana  intron  27268375    27268705    .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000169189_3;Parent=transcript:ENST00000567710
16  ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000076344_1;Parent=transcript:ENST00000316163
16  ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000076344_2;Parent=transcript:ENST00000359740
16  ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000076344_3;Parent=transcript:ENST00000397770
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/ID=gene:[^;]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  split(val,array,":")
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) array[1] ":" array[2] "_" ++b[array[2]] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code. This is only for explanation purposes for running code use above mentioned code only.

```
awk '                                            ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/ID=gene:[^;]*/){                       ##Using match function to match ID=gene: till first occurrence of semi-colon.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                  ##Creating ariable val whose value is sub-string, whose starting is RSTART till RLENGTH value.
  split(val,array,":")                           ##Splitting variable val into an array with array by setting delimiter as semi-colon.
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) array[1] ":" \     ##Printing sub-string from 1 to RSTART then array[1] : array[2] _ increasing value of array b whose index is value of array[2] sub-string starting from RSTART+RLENGTH.
        array[2] "_" ++b[array[2]] \
        substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file                                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
16  ensembl_havana  intron  27257582    27268705    .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000169189_1;Parent=transcript:ENST00000361439
16  ensembl_havana  intron  27257582    27268705    .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000169189_2;Parent=transcript:ENST00000563273
16  ensembl_havana  intron  27268375    27268705    .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000169189_3;Parent=transcript:ENST00000567710
16  ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000076344_1;Parent=transcript:ENST00000316163
16  ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000076344_2;Parent=transcript:ENST00000359740
16  ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .   -   .   ID=gene:ENSG00000076344_3;Parent=transcript:ENST00000397770
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    split($NF,vals,/;/)
    $NF = vals[1] "_" ++cnt[vals[1]] ";" vals[2]
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
16      ensembl_havana  intron  27257582        27268705        .       -       .       ID=gene:ENSG00000169189_1;Parent=transcript:ENST00000361439
16      ensembl_havana  intron  27257582        27268705        .       -       .       ID=gene:ENSG00000169189_2;Parent=transcript:ENST00000563273
16      ensembl_havana  intron  27268375        27268705        .       -       .       ID=gene:ENSG00000169189_3;Parent=transcript:ENST00000567710
16      ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .       -       .       ID=gene:ENSG00000076344_1;Parent=transcript:ENST00000316163
16      ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .       -       .       ID=gene:ENSG00000076344_2;Parent=transcript:ENST00000359740
16      ensembl_havana  intron  272932  273474  .       -       .       ID=gene:ENSG00000076344_3;Parent=transcript:ENST00000397770
```